# if p v r is satisfiable then p is satisfiable

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, satisfiability

When checking if a propositional logic is true or not, do you need to consider all possible models of it?
For example in this question:
if p v r is satisfiable then  p  is satisfiable

If you only consider the model p = false and r = true then p isn't satifisable. But if you consider all possible models of p v r, p is satisfiable, as there the exists a model p = true and r = false.
Which is the correct method to think about this?
What if p v r is valid?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Given just that example question, with no other context, I would tend to think that probably $p$ and $r$ are meant to represent possibly complex formulas and not necessarily atomic variables, and you're thinking of possible assignments to the atomic variables and looking at the results in terms of the formulas for $p$ and $r$.

Comment: **NO**: we can satisfy $p \lor r$ with the truth- assignment $v$ such taht $v(r)=$ TRUE and $v(p)=$ FALSE.

Comment: We say that a formula $A$ is *satisfiable* iff there is a truth valustation $v$ such that $v(A)=$ TRUE:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The former way is the correct way: just because $p \lor r$ is satisfiable does not mean that $p$ is satisfiable, unless $r$ implies $p$.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you consider $p$ and $r$ to be propositional variables or placeholders for possibly more complex formulas.

If they are two fixed propositional variables, then "$p \lor r$ is satisfiable" and "$p$ is satisfiable" are simply both *true*, and "if true then true" is a true claim.

However if $p$ and $r$ are placeholders, then "$p\lor r$ is satsifiable" doesn't get a truth value before you choose a concrete wff for $p$ to stand for. And in that case, it is natural to understand your claim as

> For all wffs $p$ and $r$ it holds that if $p\lor r$ is satisfiable, then $p$ is satisfiable.

And that is manifestly not the case. One counterexample is to let $p$ be $(A\land \neg A)$ and $q$ be $A$, where $A$ *is* a propositional variable.